# Jetpack Compose Modifier.background() is unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I try to build project containig this in main activity:

```
@Composable

fun JetpackCompose() {

  Box(

Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background()) {

  }

}
```

I get an error: `Unresolved reference: background`
I use jetpack compose version `1.2.0-rc02`

My imports:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*

import androidx.compose.material.Card

import androidx.compose.runtime.*

import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
```

My dependecies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"

    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'

    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"

    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

}
```

But I don't think there's anything wrong with imports and dependencies, because `fillMaxWidth()` is not unresolved reference
Why I am getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you put any parameters in the background modifier ?

Comment: @AymanAit At first, yes, but it didn't work. I simplified the code for stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add import statement

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
```

Comment: It worked for me, thanks! I've read a lot of guides, but none of them had this in them. Could you tell me where you got this information from? I haven't found any complete official documentation(referenceo) about jetpack compose

Comment: IDE suggests imports if you are using Android Studio. I rarely refer to docs for import statements.